# find and replace VIM but with interactively previous and next word like notepad++

Tags: vim, notepad++

In notepad++, you can simply `ctrl+h` to find and replace, where first field asking what word, and second field asking what should it replace. Also, there's `arrow up (previous)` and `arrow down (next)`.

That arrow button is useful because i can decide what line should i replace and what line shouldn't i replace, if i click arrow down button for example, it will select a word from previous line to next line. And if i click replace it will replace that line.

How do i do it in VIM?

I only find that arrow feature in search VIM feature with prefix `/wordFind` with click `n` for next and `shift+n` for previous, but i dont find such feature in `:s/wordFind/replacerWord` command

Comment: `:s/wordFind/replacerWord/c`

Comment: @wxz it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, you have to make it global, `:%s/wordFind/replacerWord/c`

Comment: @wxz, it works, but it doesn't work for previous word when i press ```shift+n```

Comment: That's the interactive vim sed command. You can read about the usage of `/c` by reading the vim help file by doing `:help :s_flags`. 
To change `n` to something else means changing the default behavior of vim sed, which is probably doable but would require you to write your own vim scripts to rewrite the sed command.

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira AFAIK, vim doesn't work in that way, once you press 'n', it means, "skip replacement on this match", then you cannot go back there and apply replacement once again. Therefore, "shift_n" won't move back either. It's not search, it's replacement. What you can do is defining your pattern (regex) precisely and let vim do the replacement instead of "interactively"

Comment: @wxz vim's `:s` command is for `:substitute`, it has nothing to do with `sed`.

Comment: @kent I suppose that's true. But the way vim implemented the command is so close to `sed` that I tend to think of them as the same. So when anyone rereads my comments, they should `:s/sed/substitute/` :)

Comment: @wxz if you look at `s/foo/bar` yes, it looks similar as sed 's `s` command. However, they are completely different. most `sed` supports BRE and ERE. However, vim's `:s` supports vim-regex, it's much more powerful than ERE, sometimes, it's even more convenient than PCRE. Further, vim's `:s` can call vim functions, such as `s/.../\=some-vim-function()/`

Comment: @Kent Didn't know about `:s` being able to call functions. That's cool. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest Vim equivalent would be the `/c` flag:

```
:%s/foo/bar/c
```

which allows you to accept or reject each substitution:

[image: sr]

See `:help :s_flags`. It is limited to "Next", though.

Note that, if you use Gvim, you can get a modal window, like in Notepad++, with a "Next" button but no "Previous" button:

[image: sr2]

FWIW, the MacVim GUI's equivalent of that modal window actually has a "Previous" button, for some reason:

[image: sr3]

Note that those windows are more limited in functionality than the one in Notepad++. I guess they exist more as a courtesy to casual users than anything. The manual way is the real deal, in Vim and, from experience, it is much smoother and powerful.